# How can I target a element relative to the clicked element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given the HTML structure shown below, I'm hoping that if you click on a `p` in a `ul` the `div.selected` next to that `ul` will have `.css("background", "yellow")` performed on it.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </li>
</ul>

<div>Hello Again</div>
<div class="selected">Hello Again</div>
<div><span>And Again</span></div>

<ul>
    <li>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </li>
</ul>


<div>Hello Again</div>
<div class="selected">Hello Again</div>
<div><span>And Again</span></div>
```

So far I've got;

```
$("p").next("div .selected").css("background", "yellow");
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using/ whats wrong with just `$('div.selected').css('background', 'yellow');`?

Comment: I am using it in a dynamic website. to load contents from a url and put into next div.selected

Comment: What are you supposed to be clicking to make the div yellow?

Comment: This may work for you              $("p").parents('ul').siblings("div.selected")[0].css("background-color", "yellow")

Comment: @pavan: `$("p").parents('ul').siblings("div.selected")[0]` will give you a DOM element (or undefined if no elements were matched). Either way, no `css()` method exists; `css()` is a jQuery method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'p', function () {
    $(this).closest('ul').nextAll('div.selected:first').css('background', 'yellow');
});
```

`on()` was introduced in jQuery 1.7, so if you're using an older version, try;

```
$('ul p').bind('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('ul').nextAll('div.selected:first').css('background', 'yellow');
});
```

To add a event handler to a click you need to use an [event method](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/). See also the documentation for [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on), [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) (to select the first ancestor which matches a selector), [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll) (which selects the next siblings which matches the selector; as apposed to [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next) which only considers the next element for selection).

Answer (score 2):

```
$("p").next("div .selected").addClass("selected");
```

Comment: Class cant be dynamic. i want the content in div.selected

Comment: Why are you adding the `selected` class to an element that already has the class `selected`?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to add css class to separate css from js, like this:

```
$('div.selected').addClass('className');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add the below css

```
.selected{
       bacground-color:yellow;
}
```

or you could try this

```
$("p").parents('ul').siblings("div.selected").css("background-color", "Red")
```